# update global variable value from child in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This below code is written in nodejs with mongodb. I am trying to print **temp_child_array** value in console I am getting blank array. Can any one tell me how to pass fetch data to parent.

```
let pr = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    MasterCodesModel
        .getData(key)
        .then(data => {

            let temp_child_array = [];
            let process_child = (key) => {
                MasterCodesModel
                    .getData(key)
                    .then(data => {
                        temp_child_array.push(data);
                    })
            }
            process_child(key)

            console.log("TEMP_CHILD_ARRAY: ", temp_child_array)// Its Empty
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `process_child` function has an asynchronous mongoDB task (`MasterCodesModel.getData(key).then(...)`) which is not done (either rejected or resolved) by the time you're calling `console.log`. So the result is not there yet and `temp_child_array` would have its initial value: `[]`.

You should write your `process_child` function as a Promise which when it's resolved, you have your `temp_child_array` available with your values.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am new to promise. I dont have idea how to do this. If possible then give me some reference link. Thank you

Comment: Here's the [Promise documnetation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Although I recommend using [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) syntax which is more readable and easy to use.